# how to count the number of downloads of a file with django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-staticfiles

I would like to count the number of file downloads that I put at the disposal of my user, but I can not. My site is in some ways an application library that I design, and that I can share.

I use that for Django 2, so I tried to use a middleware, but without finding what he had to do. I can count the number of pages displayed, so I told myself that I could only filter the page of the download, but I realize that it starts without changing pages.

Here are the models used:

```py
class Program (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = "Nom du Programme")
    description = models.TextField(default = "Ceci est la description d'un programme")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField (auto_now = False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField (auto_now = True, auto_now_add=False)
    image = models.ImageField (upload_to = 'images', null=True)
    download_file = models.FileField (upload_to = 'executables', null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField (default="programme_{}".format(id))
    youtube_code = models.TextField(null=True)

    stat_ref = models.OneToOneField('Stat', on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True)
    operating_system_ref = models.OneToOneField('OperatingSystem', on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you post the code that initiates the download from your template?

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering me, I supposed that it was used a middleware but, I did not know how to do it, I could not try anything

Comment: Any updates here?